# Weird issue with Calendar.getInstance()

Tags: java, oracle

I am trying to store the current timestamp in an oracle table field defined as TIMESTAMP(6).
I set it through a setter method that looks like:

```
void org.samples.Invoice.setCreated(Calendar value)
```

I am setting the field using Calendar.getInstance().

```
Invoice inv = new Invoice();
inv.setCreated(Calendar.getInstance());
```

I am seeing the timestamp that gets inserted has the correct date, but the time is always getting set as 00:00:00.0

Can you please tell me what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: show us the code where you are inserting created date to DB. May be some other code is calling invoice.getCreated() and setting the time fileds to be zero. i.e. may be a pass-by-reference side effect.

Comment: You might want to mention the technology you're using to connect with the database and provide the code for the mapping.

Comment: Never mind!! Just like how Pangea pointed out, I found the line that was resetting the timestamp to all 0s.

Comment: You should answer your own question then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be some other code is calling `invoice.getCreated()` and setting the time fileds to be zero. i.e. a pass-by-reference side effect

Answer (score 0):

From answer in comments.

> May be some other code is calling invoice.getCreated() and setting the
>   time fileds to be zero. i.e. may be a pass-by-reference side effect.
>   – Pangea Nov 8 at 22:02